# XML parser needed

Tags: xml, dom, mfc, visual-c++

i have an XML document and i want to parse it using VC++, are there any opensource parsers are available? if so please let me know with some example..

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you just need some data out of a XML document, I like to use TinyXML (http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml/). This is a small, lightweight library and I even managed it to pack it into a single file to include in your project.

Comment: +1, I recommend this every time I come across this question.

Answer (score 1):

[Xerces-C](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) has a C++-API and ok. It is a "medium busy" project, I think. More busy and more standard is [xmllib2](http://xmlsoft.org/), it has a C-API.